# How to eliminate everything except required numbers while reading from .dat file?

Tags: linux, unix, sh

I have `a .dat` file it contains data as:

```
 count ------- 234 (1 row)
```

I want to retrieve the only 234 as integer and want to store in a variable in Shell script file.

I have used the below command:

```
WORKFLOW_STATUS_COUNT=`cat status_count.dat | tr -d " "`
```

but it is getting output as:

```
count ------- 234 (1 row)
```

but expected is 234 integer value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

```
WORKFLOW_STATUS_COUNT=`cat status_count.dat | cut -d" " -f 3 `
```

`cut` splits the row with the `spacebar` delimeter and then choose only the third column

If the file come from `Windows` source you can try use `dos2unix`:

```
WORKFLOW_STATUS_COUNT=`cat status_count.dat | dos2unix | cut -d" " -f 3 `
```

Comment: I have used the above command but getting the output as
------- 
intead of number..

Comment: @PavanSingh change the `3` to `4`, perhaps you have an extra `spacebar`

Comment: When i am changing 3 to 4 i am getting output as
------- 234

Comment: Did you copy the exact input for us?

Comment: @OhadEytan:- `cut` cannot recognize multiple character delimiter. You need to use `awk`

Comment: @PavanSingh: `cut` cannot recognize multiple character delimiter. You need to use `awk`. Refer my answer

Comment: @Inian I did not used multiple character delimiter because it's not necessary for this input. `awk` is overkill for this

Comment: Is there any way to read only 3 rd column of the .dat file which is the integer value..

Comment: @PavanSingh Yes. This is exactly what my way does. You should check again you input (also for special characters)

Comment: @OhadEytan: I suspect a windows-style (CRLF) endings is screwing up the characters

Comment: I am very new to the shell scripting can u please suggest what i can use here, i haven't understood your last comment..

Comment: @PavanSingh can you give the output of `cat -A status_count.dat`?

Comment: count $
-------$
   234$
(1 row)$
$

Comment: The `$` sign stands for `newline`, so you have a file with 5 rows. To get the third line you can use: `cat status_count.dat | head -3 | tail -1`

Answer (score 0):

You could use `while read` clause to get your result. This would only work where your data columns is consistent always. E.g. If your columns of data is like this `count             258 (1 row)'(continuing space between count and 258)`, that would not work.

```
While read count_var hyphen your_var other; do
    echo $your_var
    Do_something
Done < filename.dat
```